# It has no method the_method

Tags: object, methods, ocaml

Suppose `liste` is a certain list of objects.

```
let rec sum liste any_method = match liste with
    | [] -> 0
    | obj::r -> obj#any_methode + sum r any_method
```

if I use `sum my_list_of_objects the_method`, I'll get `This expression has type int list. It has no method the_method`.

Is there a workaround to manage that issue?

**UPDATE**
Here is a simple case

```
 class point = 
    object
      val mutable x = 1
      method getx = x
      method move d = (x <- x + d)
  end;;
```

Suppose `liste_points`a list of objects `point`.

```
let func liste methode = map (fun obj -> obj#methode 5) liste;;
func liste_points move;;
```

The above little code occurred the error bellow :

```
Error: This expression has type point list
       but an expression was expected of type
         (< methode : int -> 'b; .. > as 'a) list
       Type point = < getx : int; move : int -> unit >
       is not compatible with type < methode : int -> 'b; .. > as 'a 
       The first object type has no method methode
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: This question keeps changing. You should work on making one simple, consistent, and coherent question to which you want to know the answer.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Normally, I am very consistent in my question, but the question wasn't clear. I had to modified it so that it is understandable.

Comment: Why can't I pass a method in parameter? Is there a workaround?

Comment: A method call is just a function call in essence. OCaml is a functional language, so functions are first-class values. So yes, there are workarounds. It might be better to think functionally rather than using the OO subsystem, in fact. It's quite a bit more flexible except for the "late binding" aspect.

Comment: I have a course using Ocaml right now. The teacher asked to use OO, but we can use functional paradigm as well. Can you show me how you would deal with my question? I am a bit confused right now. Your help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

Here's a little class whose instances contain two different integers:

```
class intx2 = object
    val mutable a : int = 0
    val mutable b : int = 0
    method set_a v = a <- v
    method get_a = a
    method set_b v = b <- v
    method get_b = b
end

let get_a_fn obj = obj#get_a
let get_b_fn obj = obj#get_b

let rec sum getter = function
    | [] -> 0
    | obj :: rest -> getter obj + sum getter rest
```

You can sum up the `a` values of a list of such objects like this:

```
sum get_a_fn list_of_objs
```

You can sum up the `b` values like this:

```
sum get_b_fn list_of_objs
```

Comment: I made a little mistake. I modified my question, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I added a simpler example to my question, but it doesn't work either. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It is the first time I experience O.O with Ocaml.

Comment: You changed your code, so now my answer doesn't make sense. This isn't a good practice on StackOverflow, as it creates not very useful answers. Are you sure your current code (at the very top) is what you want? It doesn't use the value `any_method` anywhere in the code.

Comment: For me, `| obj::r -> obj#methode + sum r any_method` that line makes sense as `obj#the_method` should return an integer if I run `sum my_list_of_objects the_method`

Comment: You're not using `any_method` anywhere in the code. Also you seem to be mixing up `methode` with `the_method`?

Comment: Ooh God! I am sorry for that. I have modified my question

Comment: You can't pass a method name as a parameter. There's no relation between the parameter `any_method` and the method that gets called  inside the function (which is literally named `any_method`).

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer. I suggest you work on making one simple coherent question that asks what you want to know :-)